# Speed of Robotium versus adb shell monkey

Tags: android, robotium

Running `Robotium` is very slow.

```
adb shell monkey ...
```

runs *very* fast and the GUI just *flashes* through the screens. 
As I'm new to `Robotium` I was wondering if this is normal?

Comment: What exactly is slow for you? startup time? Screen transitions? There are ways to make it faster.

Comment: Both mentioned, if you have some resources you can share, I be grateful. It's a great tool though. Wish there would be some sort of script recorder...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's normal !

> Robotium is not focused on performance, it's focus in making an API accesible by developers to make their tests easier to write and read. (Macarse)